# Using loaded script in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I had a script that was being executed as a jenkins pipeline and it was working fine. I wanted to reuse it for multiple environments so I moved all the code to functions and load them from multiple files.

Library file - **Healthcheck**:

```
#!groovy

@NonCPS
def check(type) {
    stage "prepare"
    echo "TEST1"
    props = readProperties file:'build.properties'
    echo "TEST2"
    stage "queues"
    checkQueues()
}

@NonCPS
def checkQueues() {
    txt = "http://ltxl0207.sgdcelab.sabre.com:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=!/tss!/trip_source_updates,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker/QueueSize".toURL().getText(requestProperties: [Authorization: "Basic " + "admin:admin".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()])
    json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(txt)
    echo "Got response: " + txt
}
return this;
```

File that uses it - **Healthcheck-dev**:

```
#!groovy

node {
    checkout scm
    healthcheck = load 'Healthcheck'
    healthcheck.check('DEV')
}
```

And the trouble is that the script doesn't get pass `readProperties` and the prepare stage it just stops there, ignoring the queues stage:

```
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (Healthcheck)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] stage (prepare)
Entering stage prepare
Proceeding
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

What I'm doing wrong? When I move the code to single file it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to execute your pipeline with your 2 files ("`Healthcheck`" & "`Healtcheck-dev`") being in the same repository ? Because when you load a script from another SCM repo like you seem to be doing, Jenkins actually creates another directory `@script` or such for your loaded script.

You might need to do something like this to load your general script from the correct workspace :

```
node {
    checkout scm
    dir("${projectWorkspace}@script") {
        healthcheck = load 'Healthcheck'
        healthcheck.check('DEV')
    }
}
```

with `${projectWorkspace}` being the original workspace for your build.

Comment: I'm using the same repo for those files, they sit just next to each other.

Comment: What about the `build.properties` file you are trying to read properties from ? You are using `checkout scm` but your initial workspace containing your groovy scripts and the checkout workspace containing the `build.properties` file might not be the same, hence resulting in your properties file not being found.
Can you try accessing your properties file from `${projectWorkspace}@script/build.properties` instead ?

Comment: but why it works when I have only one Healthcheck file? `checkout scm` is needed for the build to work (it is needed to checkout the full git repo)

Comment: I'm not sure about the one vs two files problem but I think it's workspace-related. If you have access to the Jenkins machine, please try to go your project folder(s) (by default `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/your-project*`) and look for files in the different folders (`...your-project`, `...your-project@script`, `your-project@tmp`, etc). That might give you a better view of what is going on.